# Best way to merge two or more list in python preserving order

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

Is there a more pythonic way to do it ?

Input:

```
list1 =  [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4]]
list2 =  [['e',5],['f',6],['g',7],['h',8]]
```

Desired Output:

```
out = [['a',1],['e',5],['b',2],['f',6],['c',3],['g',7],['d',4] ,['h',8]]
```

I have done:

```
def mergePreserveOrder(*argv):      
    for arg in argv:  
        for arg2 in argv: 
            if(len(arg) != len(arg2)) :
                print("arrays size do not match" + str(arg) +  str(arg2))                
                return 
    output = []    
    for index in range (len(argv[0])):    
        for arg in argv:
            output.append(arg[index])    
    return  output

mergePreserveOrder (list1 ,list2  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most general solution is the `roundrobin` recipe from [the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

list1 =  [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4]]
list2 =  [['e',5],['f',6],['g',7],['h',8]]

print(list(roundrobin(list1, list2)))
```

which produces your desired output.

Unlike `chain`+`zip`, this solution will work with uneven length inputs, where `zip` will silently drop all elements beyond the length of the shortest input.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `zip` along with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2)))
```

**Example**:

```
from itertools import chain

list1 = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4]]
list2 = [['e',5],['f',6],['g',7],['h',8]]

print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2))))
# [['a', 1], ['e', 5], ['b', 2], ['f', 6], ['c', 3], ['g', 7], ['d', 4], ['h', 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*zip(list1, list2)))
[['a', 1], ['e', 5], ['b', 2], ['f', 6], ['c', 3], ['g', 7], ['d', 4], ['h', 8]]
```